# failed to load resources or couldn't find the module. importing images in vuejs component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, commonjs, esmodules

I'm trying to import my images, but i get couldn't find module or failed to load resources. I've used the require function, but it doesn't work too!

```
`<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
      <h2>{{ product.title }}</h2>
      <img :src="product.link" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      products: [
        {
          title: "cotton",
          link: `./assets/images/cotton.jpg`,
          id: 1,
        },
        {
          title: "purse",
          link: "./assets/images/purse.jpg",
          id: 2,
        },
        {
          title: "leather",
          link: "./assets/images/leather.jpg",
          id: 3,
        },
        {
          title: "wallet",
          link: "./assets/images/wallet.jpg",
          id: 4,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>`
```

images are in the root directory @/assets/images/*.jpg

1. I have used require function it didn't work
2. tried both absolute and relative path for src attribute

Comment: Whats your configuration of vue.config.js ? You should have a property assetsDir with '/assets' as value and in your component you show the images with link: '/images'

Comment: this is my vue.confing.js and i also add assetsDir as you mentioned,
const { defineConfig } = require("@vue/cli-service");
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  assetsDir: "./src/assets",
});